# Using Ruby to track updated information?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, web-crawler

The script I am trying to build works like this.

1. User directs application to a webpage containing a number that represents total # of miles traveled
2. Application saves that number
3. User comes back 30 minutes later after traveling
4. Application returns miles per hour

Right now I can do step 1. I'm struggling to get my application to save the number the user obtained in step 1.

Ideally, this should work like a timer. The user starts the timer, goes for a drive, comes back, stops the timer, and his average speed is returned to him.

Is Ruby and Rails enough? Or will I need some sort of AJAX or JavaScript?

Answer (score 1):

Ruby on Rails is enough. You can keep the starting time as data in step 1, and call that in step 3 or 4.

Comment: Hmm... Mind checking out my latest question? It will help me to understand this more fully.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're getting confused between how Rails, JS & Ajax work

Rails is backend; will handle your db & requests. JS / Ajax will process any front-end requests made directly by the client in the browser

---

**Make Another Model**

What you're asking is actually quite simple if you break it into [modular](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_design) pieces

1. `User` doesn't have many miles; a `User's` `Trip` has many miles
2. Therefore, I'd introduce a new model call `Trip`
3. Each `Trip` will have many miles
4. You can create a new join model call `TripMiles` which you'll be able to store the miles in
5. Once you've got the miles in this model, you can use the `created_at` times to see how many miles per hour

Here are some examples:

```
#app/models/user.rb
Class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :trips
end

#app/models/trip.rb
Class Trip < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
    has_many :miles, :class_name => "TripMile"
end

#app/models/trip_mile.rb
Class TripMile < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :trip
end

trips
id | user_id | created_at | updated_at 

trip_miles
id | trip_id | created_at | updated_at
```

This will allow you to set the `trip` as a specific record, and then add as many miles to it through the `trip_miles` model. How you add these will depend on your front-end, but it will all be Rails

Comment: Why would you need a model for a mile? All the OP wants as mile is the quantity. In fact, the mile may not even be an integer. This answer does not seem to make sense.

Comment: I made the extra model to accommodate any miles he may want to put into the app. The model is for `TripMile`, meaning that it will record any miles per trip, which would give the ability to add as many miles as you wanted

Comment: Thanks, Rich. I'll play around with what you've mentioned and see where it gets me. You're always a great help. Happy holidays, by the way.

@sawa - Have you got any more detailed suggestions?

Comment: Thanks bud - @sawa, The way I saw the question was that the OP wanted to know whether it was a Rails / JS job, but more pertinently, wanted to see how you'd set up the models to handle the data. Having a miles model will give you the ability to add as many miles as required per trip. Of course, if trip only has 1 set of miles, you could just have `start_miles` & `end_miles` in the `Trip` model

Comment: However, as is the case with many applications, you'll typically find a lot of functionality needs to be added later on. Having the extra model would accommodate that, although it's probably currently too much. Perhaps @DylanRichards would elaborate on the use case?

Comment: Sure, @RichPeck -- I'd love to elaborate. I actually used miles/hour to simplify the case. This question pertains to the application I am working with:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20730591/sorting-crawled-information

The user is actually the player of a game. He wants to track how much experience he is gaining per hour. Take the first example.

The user 'Brink' has overall experience of 1287238956. When the user plays, this number gets larger. When the user logs out, the webpage I crawled this information is updated. My goal is to track how much this number would go up in an hour...

Comment: if he continued to play at that speed. So the average.

Comment: Okay, well my model might come in handy here. What you can do is populate your `miles` model with constant updates of the miles / points. This means you'll have an accurate running-total of all the miles / points created by a particular trip / game. I often see people making really basic apps, to accommodate current functionality, but you *really* want to have extensible functionality, which can be scaled (within reason of course)

Comment: Calculating the average speed gets more accurate the more data you have. So I'd keep the miles model, and focus on creating a function to calculate the MPH average of the entries. If you have more than 2 (start & end), I'd use as much data as possible to calculate the average - this will give you a very accurate figure